# Does Titanic (1997) really show these 3 pictures of Rose Dawson and her new family?

Tags: titanic

I quote the following from p. 154 of [the screenplay with the alternative ending](http://www.pages.drexel.edu/~ina22/splaylib/Screenplay-Titanic.pdf):

[image]

Are the pictures for 1-3 (that I added in red above) really exhibited? I do not see them [in this Youtube video](https://youtu.be/xPlGPpS9hl0?t=42s) that shows only 'Rose as a young actress in California [...]'.

Comment: Lol! I'm pretty sure the roller coaster wasn't on the pier in 1920. Even the carousel wasn't there until 1922. Too funny!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You show them.

[image]
College one is first red from right. Children and grandchildren one is likely second red from right, next to the college one. The actress one is likely the one with the bi-plane.